# Create a new dictionary combining two dictionaries with equal keys without changing source dictionary

Tags: python

I have these two dicts:

```
a = {'blocked': [29.686],
 'dns': [-1],
 'connect': [-1],
 'send': [0.09],
 'wait': [36.912],
 'receive': [0.24],
 'ssl': [-1],
 '_queued': [4.029]}
 
b = {'blocked': [0],
 'dns': [0],
 'connect': [28.219],
 'send': [0.126],
 'wait': [33.053],
 'receive': [0.279],
 'ssl': [28.219],
 '_queued': [1.312]}
```

And I want to obtain that result (extend value for each key):

```
c = {'blocked': [29.686, 0], 
'dns': [-1, 0], 
'connect': [-1, 28.219], 
'send': [0.09, 0.126], 
'wait': [36.912, 33.053], 
'receive': [0.24, 0.279], 
'ssl': [-1, 28.219], 
'_queued': [4.029, 1.312]}
```

So I wrote this:

```
c = {k: v.append(*b[k]) for k, v in a.items()}
```

or also:

```
c = {k: v.extend(b[k]) for k, v in a.items()}
```

But `append` and `extend` return None and dict `c` is filled with those None. The dict `a` is also changed to what c was intended as a result.

```
c -> {'blocked': None, 'dns': None, 'connect': None, 'send': None, 'wait': None, 'receive': None, 'ssl': None, '_queued': None}
```

I know I can copy `a` to `c` and then do the operation without assigning the dictionary to anything getting `c` modified

```
c = a # trick
{k: v.extend(b[k]) for k, v in c.items()}
```

Is there a clean way to do this without using a "passing" dictionary to not change `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want list concatenation:

```py
c = { k : v + b[k] for k, v in a.items() }
```

Output:

```
{
 'blocked': [29.686, 0],
 'dns': [-1, 0],
 'connect': [-1, 28.219],
 'send': [0.09, 0.126],
 'wait': [36.912, 33.053],
 'receive': [0.24, 0.279],
 'ssl': [-1, 28.219],
 '_queued': [4.029, 1.312]
}
```

If it's possible that there are keys in `a` that do not exist in `b`, use `b.get` with a default empty list rather than `b[k]`:

```py
c = { k : v + b.get(k, []) for k, v in a.items() }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Any explanation of why the behaviour of my code was that?

Comment: @DennisGrasso your code modified `a` because the `v` values in your comprehensions were *references* to the lists in `a`, so when you modified them in the comprehension it modified the values in `a`.